# SQL: No records found. Handling no errors found

Tags: sql, oracle

I created this SQL code because I need to rank an specific list of ISIN's. Therefore, I have been using the following code to get the results:

```
var r refcursor;

begin
   msa.exl_stifel_ms ('01/01/2017',
                      '21/01/2018',
                      'GBP',
                      'CB',
                      'JE00BYR8GK67',
                      'UBS',
                      :r);
end;
```

and I get 'no records' found.. which is obviously wrong and indicates that's something wrong with the query.... any advice?

```
create or replace procedure msa.exl_stifel_ms (
   tradedatestart   in     date,
   tradedateend     in     date,
   inccy            in     varchar,
   inbtype          in     varchar,
   invariable       in     varchar,
   inbroker         in     varchar,
   test                out sys_refcursor)
as
   inbrokerid   integer;
begin
   delete from tt_exl_out;

   delete from isins_tt;

   delete from tt_exl_indexdetail;

   delete from index_tt;

   select brokerid
     into inbrokerid
     from msa.client
    where clientname = inbroker;

   insert into isins_tt (isin)
      select distinct effectiveisin
        from msa.instrument inst
       where inst.isin = invariable; --will need to loop through all the ISINs here

   rp_calctrnbicdetailtotals (inccy,
                              inbtype,
                              tradedatestart,
                              tradedateend);


   insert into tt_exl_indexdetail (isin,
                                   brokerid,
                                   brokercode,
                                   brokertotal)
        select i.effectiveisin,
               ba.brokerid,
               (select br2.brokercode
                  from broker br2
                 where br2.brokerid = ba.brokerid),
               sum (t.total)
          from bicisintotal_tt t
               inner join bank ba
                  on t.bicid = ba.bicid and ba.includeinreport = 1
               inner join instrument i on t.isin = i.isin
      group by ba.brokerid, i.effectiveisin;

   update tt_exl_indexdetail tt1
      set percentage =
             (select case x.totalvalue
                        when 0 then 0
                        else (i.brokertotal / x.totalvalue)
                     end
                        as percentage
                from index_tt i,
                     (select sum (brokertotal) as totalvalue from index_tt) x
               where brokerid = tt1.brokerid);


   insert into tt_exl_out (yearno,
                           rank,
                           turnover,
                           marketshare)
      select id1.brokerid,
             dense_rank () over (order by id1.brokertotal desc),
             id1.brokertotal,
             id1.percentage
        from index_tt id1;

   open test for
      select rank,
             c.clientname,
             turnover,
             marketshare
        from tt_exl_out tt3
             inner join msa.client c on tt3.yearno = c.brokerid
       where c.clientname = inbroker;
end;
```

Comment: Posting some code and asking for "any advice?" seems... lazy? Can you ask an actual question?

Comment: I would suggest stepping through and manually running each of those select queries in your SQL client, filling in the variables with those test values. It should be easy to spot which one returns zero rows.

Comment: What is the point of selecting the brokerid in the first place? You don't appear to be using inbrokerid anywhere after you populate it!

Comment: By `no records found` and `no errors found`, did you mean `no rows selected`? If so, this is the standard summary that SQL*Plus prints when a refcursor returns no rows. It's not an error, and your procedure cannot tell whether any rows are going to be returned or not since it is the caller that fetches the result set, not the procedure. Perhaps it should check whether the `insert into tt_exl_out` did anything?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm wrong this:

```
select brokerid
     into inbrokerid
     from msa.client
    where clientname = inbroker
```

is the only SELECT that could return NO-DATA-FOUND (if that's what you call "no records found"). Other SELECTs are part of INSERT or UPDATE statements, so they simply won't do anything, but won't raise an error either.

You also call `rp_calctrnbicdetailtotals` - I don't know what it does, but - it could be a candidate for an error as well.

Try to run that code in SQL*Plus, it'll tell you exact spot of an error (PL/SQL object name, line number) so you might be able to fix it. Make sure you remove all WHEN OTHERS exception handlers (if there are any).

**[EDIT, after seeing @kfinity's comment]**

As I said, I think not. Here's an example; the first SELECT returns *nothing*, there's no employee with EMPNO = -1 (so, as you said, it would return no-data-found):

```
SQL> var pe refcursor
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (test out sys_refcursor) is
  2  begin
  3    open test for
  4      select ename
  5        from emp
  6        where empno = -1;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test (:pe)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print pe

no rows selected
```

See? No error.

However, if it was an *ordinary* SELECT ... INTO, then yes - it would raise it:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2    l_ename varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    select ename into l_ename
  5      from emp
  6      where empno = -1;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test
BEGIN p_test; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "HR.P_TEST", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

**[EDIT #2]**

Yes, as Alessandro said, it should then be handled by the EXCEPTION section.

Comment: I think the last query (opening the refcursor) could also return NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: `select...into...` can raise exception `NO_DATA_FOUND`. to handle this exception wrap the `SELECT` statement with `BEGIN [SELECT... INTO...] EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN [do something] END`

Comment: I think not, @kfinity. I edited my message, have a look.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks for checking.